# Zusammensetzung mit festem Begriff aus Adjektiv und Substantiv

Tags: translation, english-to-german, compound

Ich bin am Versuch gescheitert, ein englisches Fachwort ins Deutsche zu übersetzen: *bond critical point*.

Ein *critical point* ist ein **kritischer Punkt** (aus der Mathematik), ein [fester Begriff aus Adjektiv und Substantiv](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D89).

Ein *bond point* wäre leicht mit **Bindungspunkt** (oder **Bindungs-Punkt**) übersetzt.

Wäre die korrekte Übersetzung für *bond critical point* dann **Bindungs-kritischer-Punkt**? Das Adjektiv inmitten der Zusammensetzung kommt mir komisch vor, die mutmaßlich alternative Übersetzung **kritischer Bindungspunkt** ist aber sicher falsch, da ein **Bindungspunkt** alleine (d.h. ohne "kritisch" nicht existiert).

**Erklärung:** Ein kritischer Punkt allgemein ist ein Punkt, an dem der Gradient (die mehrdimensionale Ableitung) verschwindet. In der mehrdimensionalen Analysis können diese Punkte lokale Maxima, lokale Minima oder Sattelpunkte sein. Ein BCP ist ein Sattelpunkt zweiter Ordnung der Elektronendichte (also ein kritischer Punkt). Diese Punkte liegen im Raum immer auf dem Rücken der Dichte der die lokalen Maxima in zwei Atomkernen verbindet und werden daher mit der Bindung assoziiert.

Comment: Du solltest erst einmal die Bedeutung von "bond critical point" erklären.

Comment: Ich kenne "bcp" (bond critical point) nur aus der Chemie.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ein kritischer Punkt allgemein ist ein Punkt, an dem der Gradient verschwindet. Ein BCP ist ein Sattelpunkt zweiter Ordnung der Elektronendichte. Diese Punkte liegen im Raum immer zwischen zwei Atomkernen und werden daher mit der Bindung assoziiert.

Comment: Falls es darum geht, den Begriff in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit (z.B. Bachelorarbeit) zu verwenden, so spricht nichts dagegen, ihn einfach als englisches Fachwort zu nutzen.

Comment: @infinitezero Danke, aber es war tatsächlich aus reinem Interesse, wie die deutsche Sprache einen solchen Fall behandelt. Is "Bindungs-kritischer-Punkt" überhaupt korrekte Rechtschreibung?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wie wäre es damit?

#### kritischer Punkt der Bindung

Ich denke das ist genau das, was der englische Ausdruck *»bond critical point«* aussagt.

Prinzipiell kann jedes geschlossene Kompositum, das aus zwei Substantiven besteht, in eine Konstruktion mit einem Genitivattribut umgewandelt werden. Das auch genau der Vorgang, den man macht, wenn man solche Begriffe in Sprachen übersetzt, die keine geschlossene Komposita kennen, oder sie nur sehr begrenzt verwenden.

Dass das immer möglich ist, heißt aber nicht, dass das immer eine gute Wahl wäre. Oft gibt es bessere Alternativen. Hier sind ein paar Beispiele:

- Wohnzimmer = Zimmer des Wohnens (Zimmer, in dem gewohnt wird)
- Eiscreme = Creme des Eises (Creme aus Eis)
- Kaffeetasse = Tasse des Kaffees (Tasse für Kaffee)

Beim Begriff *bond critical point* besteht das Problem ja darin, dass es hier um einen Punkt im Raum geht, der sich in einer chemischen Bindung befindet. Es ist also ein Bindungspunkt. Und gleichzeitig ist diese Punkt kritisch. Er wäre unter normalen Umständen also so zu bezeichnen:

> kritischer Bindungspunkt

Allerdings geht dabei die feste Fügung zwischen *kritisch* und *Punkt* verloren, und da kann man eben sehr schön dadurch umgehen, dass man das geschlossene Kompositum durch eine Nominalgruppe mit einem Genitivattribut ersetzt:

> kritischer Punkt der Bindung

Damit bleibt der *kritische Punkt* als fester Begriff erhalten, und die Verbindung zwischen den Begriffen *Bindung* und *kritischer Punkt* ist ebenfalls korrekt wiedergegeben.

Comment: +1 Das ist das einzige, das man da machen kann. Aus dem Ausdruck "kritischer Punkt" kann man nun mal kein zusammengesetztes Substantiv machen, also kann man den Ausdruck auch nicht als zusammengesetztes Substantiv erweitern.